# Why does Doctrine ORM preUpdate event execute endlessly when creating a notification for an Order status change in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities in my symfony project: Order, Notification.I need create a notification when "status" field of Order was changed.I created OrderEventSubscriber which implements Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\EventSubscriber\EventSubscriberInterface and subscribe to the Doctrine\ORM\Events::preUpdate event.

When i create in preUpdate method new notification and save it in DB with flush preUpdate starts to execute endlessly although in preUpdate.
Code of preUpdate method:

`public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
$entity = $args->getObject();

```
    if ($entity instanceof Order) {
        $onlyStatusChanged = count($args->getEntityChangeSet()) === 1 && $args->hasChangedField('status');
        if ($onlyStatusChanged) {
            $this->notificationsCreator->createChangeStatusNotification($entity->getCustomer());
        }
    }
}`
```

Notification is creating in createChangeStatusNotification method:

`public function createChangeStatusNotification(User $recipient)
{
$notification = new Notification();
$notification->setAction((new DataMapping())->getKeyByValue('notification_actions', 'order_status_changed'));
$notification->setRecipient($recipient);
$notification->setCreatedAt(new DateTimeImmutable('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow')));

```
    $this->em->persist($notification);
    $this->em->flush();
}`
```

I have checking of instance of updated entity. If it is not instance of Order i`m stopping executing of method.

Answer (score 0):

try this implementation ?

```
<?php

namespace App\EntityListener;

use App\Entity\Order;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;

class OrderListener
{
    public function preUpdate(Order $order, PreUpdateEventArgs $event): void
    {
        if (isset($event->getEntityChangeSet()['status'])) {
            $this->notificationsCreator->createChangeStatusNotification($order->getCustomer());
        }
    }
}
```

in your services.yaml :

```
App\EntityListener\OrderListener:
    tags:
        - { name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener', event: 'preUpdate', entity: 'App\Entity\Order' }
```